# OOP / try except statements in __init__ of class

Tags: python, oop, try-catch, init, except

I want to control the input of the class `Webpage`. Meaning, I want to be sure that the webpage's link is appropriately provided, e.g. `'http://example.com'`.

```
class Webpage(object):
    def __init__(self, link):
        prefix = ['http', 'https']
        suffix = ['com', 'net']
        try:
            if link.split(':')[0] in prefix and link.split('.')[-1] in suffix:
                self.link = link
        except:
            raise ValueError('Invalid link') 


   def get_link(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.link outside of the class

        Returns: self.link
        '''
        return self.link

   def __str__(self):
        return str(self.link)
```

However, when I try code:

```
test_link = Webpage('example.com')
```

I do not get `ValueError`, as I would expect. Call of methods:

```
test_link.get_link()
print(test_lint)
```

result in

```
AttributeError: 'Webpage' object has no attribute 'link'
```

which indicates that try/except worked partially - `try` did not execute `self.link = link`, however `except` statement wasn't executed.

An example:

```
test_link = Webpage('http://example.com')
```

works fine with `get_link()` and `print` methods of that class.

Will appreciate any hint.

Comment: The url "example.com" doesn't pass your `if` statement: `if link.split(':')[0] in prefix and link.split('.')[-1] in suffix:`.

Comment: Maybe what you wanted is to raise the exception in an `else` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raising an expection as in your case ValueError is done in the try block and handling of the expection it is done in the except block

For more information please visit [Raising Expections in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)

```
class Webpage(object):
    def __init__(self, link):
        prefix = ['http', 'https']
        suffix = ['com', 'net']
        try:
            if link.split(':')[0] in prefix and link.split('.')[-1] in suffix:

                self.link = link
            else:
                raise ValueError('Invalid link')
        except ValueError as exp:
            print("the value error is {}\nthe link specified is {} ".format(exp,link))



    def get_link(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.link outside of the class

        Returns: self.link
        '''
        return self.link

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.link) 

test_link = Webpage('example.com')
```

Output

```
the value error is Invalid link
the link specified is example.com
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Works like a charm! That ".format(exp,link)" also does the job. Many thanks, Albin Paul. M

Comment: I agree there is no specfic point in this context . I just was illustrating how we can force an exception and handle it using except .

Comment: I also thought the same, I guess this example is simply not suitable to practice on the try/except thing...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` and create the `raise` in else.

**Demo:**

```
class Webpage(object):
    def __init__(self, link):
        prefix = ('http', 'https')
        suffix = ('com', 'net')
        if (link.startswith(prefix)) and (link.endswith(suffix)):
            self.link = link
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid link') 

    def get_link(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.link outside of the class

        Returns: self.link
        '''
        return self.link

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.link)  

test_link = Webpage( 'example.com')
print(test_link.get_link())
```

Comment: Hey Rakesh. As below, I wanted to use "try/except" to practice that as well - I was able to do "if/else" way. However, those `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` are very nice! Thanks, M.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try:
            if link.split(':')[0] in prefix and link.split('.')[-1] in suffix:
                self.link = link
        except:
            raise ValueError('Invalid link')
```

If you pass link `example.com`, if statement fails since it does not contain any pre mentioned prefix. Since its logically correct, it will never go down to `except` block. 
You may probably want to check if `self.link` exists inside `get_link` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated code

```
class Webpage(object):
    def __init__(self, link):
        prefix = ['http', 'https']
        suffix = ['com', 'net']
        if link.split(':')[0] in prefix and link.split('.')[-1] in suffix:
            self.link = link
        else:
            self.link = 'Invalid link'


    def get_link(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.link outside of the class

        Returns: self.link
        '''
        return self.link

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.link)

test_link = Webpage('example.com')
test_link.get_link()
print(test_link)
```

Comment: Thanks Dithon for your effort. However, I wanted to use "try/except" to practice that as well - I was able to do "if/else" way. Best, M

Comment: @mmikeel: Just change the `self.link = 'Invalid link'` to `raise ValueError('Invalid link')`. You can practice handling exceptions by putting the `test_link = Webpage('example.com')` statement inside a `try/except`.